Playwright recording tests runs slow/juddery
I'm on version 1.46 of Playwright. Whenever I record a test in Chromium Browser that opens, I can only get halfway through my test because it starts to get very sluggish and slow. Clicking a dropdown takes a while to load. What can I do to remedy the problem? CPU and Memory aren't maxed out but they do go up significantly when Chromium is running.
Expecting it to run a lot smoother, no sluggishness or hang ups.

Please share a [mcve] and environment details.
